# I need to find the Center of Mass for an image containing 15 different sized and coloured buttons

Tags: coordinates, center

Using the image processing, we can find the Center Of Mass assuming that each pixel represents a particle comprising an object. Assume that each particle’s weight for all buttons is equal, then how to find the Center of mass for all each particle in an image? Where Center of Mass xc = sum of (mi*xi)/M & yc = sum of (mi*yi)/M where M=sum(mi) for i=1,2,...,n